Store Multiple Values in an Enum
I have an enum of different States of an user in a Db,
public enum UserState {
    ACTIVE = 0,
    INACTIVE = 1,
    MEMORIAL = 2,
    APPLICATION = 3,
}

I need to assign multiple value to each of these states.
I need to assign a URL for redirection, and also a string with the name of the state.
How can I store those 2 values in my enum and get them without having to declare multiple classes or using configuration files?
I tried to use [Description] Attribute to store one
public enum UserState {
    [Description("Active user")]
    ACTIVE = 0,
    [Description("Inactive user")]
    INACTIVE = 1,
    [Description("Dead user")]
    MEMORIAL = 2,
    [Description("Application")]
    APPLICATION = 3,
}

And with this I was able to retrieve the name of the state using
public class UserStateExtension{

    public static string GetStateName(UserState actualState)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute[] descriptionAttributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])actualState
            .GetType()
            .GetField(actualState.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return descriptionAttributes.Length > 0 ? descriptionAttributes[0].Description : string.Empty;
    }
}

Is there a method to use a similar trick for the UrlRedirection?

Sounds like it should be a class or struct rather than an enum.

@MatthewWatson Yes I know but I found myself in a situation where the enum was enough at first and then when I needed to refactor I tried to imagine a way to solve it keeping the Enum.  Dont worry my code is clean

This question is opinion-based, please add more details.

@shingo What is opinion-based about this? OP states a clear desired outcome and parameters that are required (store 2 values in an enum and retrieve them without having to declare multiple classes).

@TylerH, however, the author himself provided 5 approaches, the other answers also provide more opinions, and currently you cannot choose the correct answer based on a certain fact.

@shingo I provide different approches but none of them where what i was asking for. I wanted something like in my example so enum related. I ended up by finding how to create and use CustomAttributes. the thing is that in my question i didn't know that it existed.

The usage Of CustomAttributes seems more suitable for the question.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class UserAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _urlRedirection;
    private readonly string _typeString;

    public UserAttribute(string typeString, string urlRedirection)
    {
        this._typeString = typeString;
        this._urlRedirection = urlRedirection;
    }

    public virtual string UrlRedirection { get { return _urlRedirection; } }
    public virtual string TypeString { get { return _typeString; } }
}

By creating a customAttribute like this you are able to have as much parameters as you want. Also it's more readable than having wrongly named Attribute when using the Predefined ones.
This is how the Enum can use it
public enum UserState {
    [UserAttribute("Active user", "/user")]
    ACTIVE = 0,
    [UserAttribute("Inactive user", "/logout")]
    INACTIVE = 1,
    [UserAttribute("Dead user", "/logout")]
    MEMORIAL = 2,
    [UserAttribute("Application", "/app")]
    APPLICATION = 3,
}

And then to get a specific variable from the Attribute it's like before
public static string GetUrlRedirection(UserState actualState)
    {
        UserAttribute[] attribute = (UserAttribute[])actualState
            .GetType()
            .GetField(actualState.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserAttribute), false);
            return attribute.Length > 0 ? attribute[0].UrlRedirection : string.Empty; // Replace UrlRedirection with the property you want to get
    }


Maybe an enum is not the best data type for you. If you have to store several information, a class might be better. In order to get the enum-like behaviour of just having a few possible values, you can make your constructor private and have some public static instances:
public class UserState
{
   public string Id {get; private set; }

   public int Value {get; private set; }

   public string Description {get; private set; }

   public string Url {get; private set; }

   private UserState() { }

   public static UserState Active { get; }
         = new UserState { Id = "ACTIVE", Value = 0, Description = "Active User", Url = "http://www.active.com/" };

   public static UserState Inactive{ get; }
      = new UserState { Id = "INACTIVE", Value = 1, Description = "Inactive User", Url = "http://www.inactive.com/" };

     // and so on for the other states

     //the following can be very nice when looping over all possible states
     // or if you want to find a state with a certain Value
     public static IEnumerable<UserState> PossibleStates
     {
        get
        {
          yield return Active;
          yield return Inactive;
          // and so on for the other states
        }
      }
}

Usage is
UserState myUserState = UserState.Active;
Console.WriteLine(myUserState.Description + " has the url " + myUserState.Url);


Would using extension methods be suitable? For example:
public static class UserStateExt
{
    public static string Description(this UserState userState)
    {
        return userState switch
        {
            UserState.ACTIVE      => "Active User",
            UserState.INACTIVE    => "Inactive User",
            UserState.MEMORIAL    => "Dead User",
            UserState.APPLICATION => "Application",

            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(userState), userState, null)
        };
    }

    public static string UriRedirection(this UserState userState)
    {
        return userState switch
        {
            UserState.ACTIVE      => "active redir",
            UserState.INACTIVE    => "inactive redir",
            UserState.MEMORIAL    => "memorial redir",
            UserState.APPLICATION => "app redir",

            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(userState), userState, null)
        };
    }
}

Then you can write code like
UserState state = UserState.INACTIVE; 
Console.WriteLine(state.Description());


Yet another way is to define a readonly struct as a fake enum:
readonly struct UserState
{
    readonly int stateId;
    readonly string redirectUrl;

    public static readonly UserState ACTIVE = new(0, "/user");
    public static readonly UserState INACTIVE = new(1, "/logout");
    public static readonly UserState MEMORIAL = new(2, "/logout");
    public static readonly UserState APPLICATION = new(3, "/app");

    private UserState(int state, string url)
        => (stateId, redirectUrl) = (state, url);

    public static implicit operator int(UserState value)
        => value.stateId;
    
    public static implicit operator string(UserState value)
        => value.redirectUrl;
}


It has two private members to store the related values (state's id and the redirect url)
It has a private constructor so, no new members could be created outside of the struct
It has 4 static public members to expose the different options
It has two implicit conversion operator to either retrieve the state's ide or the redirect url

The usage:
var state = UserState.INACTIVE;
string url = state;
int id = state;
url.Dump(); // /logout
id.Dump(); // 1

Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PFS7rg

If you truly dont want to use anything else than the base Enum:
You can store a second value by using the CategoryAttribute
In our case we will have something like this:
public enum UserState {
    [Description("Active user"), Category("/user")]
    ACTIVE = 0,
    [Description("Inactive user"), Category("/logout")]
    INACTIVE = 1,
    [Description("Dead user"), Category("/logout")]
    MEMORIAL = 2,
    [Description("Application"), Category("/app")]
    APPLICATION = 3,
}

And in order to get the Category for a specific UserState you can add a second method
public static string GetUrlRedirection(UserState actualState)
    {
        CategoryAttribute[] categoryAttributes = (CategoryAttribute[])actualState
            .GetType()
            .GetField(actualState.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false);
            return categoryAttributes.Length > 0 ? categoryAttributes[0].Category : string.Empty;
    }


Otherwise I would recommend using a switch
public string? getRedirectionUrl(UserState actualState)
{
    switch(actualState)
    {
        case UserState.ACTIVE:
            return "/user";
        case UserState.INACTIVE: case UserState.MEMORIAL:
            return "/logout";
        case UserState.APPLICATION:
            return "/app"
        default:
            return "/"
    }
}

The switch is for me the best option because of the maintability and the fact that you can add even more property without any problem.

Another solution can be using a second Enum with all the values linked to the first one
public enum UrlRedirectionEnum
{
    [Description("/app")]
    LOGOUT = UserState.APPLICATION
}

But this one wont work when you have multiple value that need the same redirectionUrl or you'll have to write it twice in the Enum (one for both value)
Example :
public enum UrlRedirectionEnum
{
    [Description("/logout")]
    LOGOUT = UserState.INACTIVE,
    [Description("/logout")]
    LOGOUT = UserState.MEMORIAL
}


You could simply just create a ImmutableDictionary<UserState, Uri>  to store your mapping separately from the enum.

Maybe you can try use Ardalis SmartEnum library (https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum)
It express enums as classes but with the support of native enum syntax. It also supports model binding, ef core, serialization, etc...
Here is the sample code from github which uses inheritance to add custom behaviour to your enums
using Ardalis.SmartEnum;

public abstract class EmployeeType : SmartEnum<EmployeeType>
{
    public static readonly EmployeeType Manager = new ManagerType();
    public static readonly EmployeeType Assistant = new AssistantType();

    private EmployeeType(string name, int value) : base(name, value)
    {
    }

    public abstract decimal BonusSize { get; }

    private sealed class ManagerType : EmployeeType
    {
        public ManagerType() : base("Manager", 1) {}

        public override decimal BonusSize => 10_000m;
    }

    private sealed class AssistantType : EmployeeType
    {
        public AssistantType() : base("Assistant", 2) {}

        public override decimal BonusSize => 1_000m;
    }
}


Seems like overkill for a such simple task

Agree. But simple solutions were already mentioned and I saw this lib in some projects so maybe the author will find it useful)
